# When having more sql statements to export TsFile data in Apache IoTDB, why did less results been executed?

Tags: export, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I would like to ask when using TsFile exporting tool in Apache IoTDB, I have 40 sql statements in my sql file, but only 3 TsFiles are exported. What is the reason for this? Did the exporting tool exports data by traversing the sql file one by one?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, if no data is found in a certain SQL statement for exporting data in Apache IoTDB, the entire task will be stopped. You can write a shell outside to call this exported sh file to enter your SQL statements, so that even if one of the SQL statements returns no results, you can still continue to export data using other SQL statements.